# Visual Studio 2019 VSIX installation errors

Tags: vsix, visual-studio-2019

No matter what VSIX I try to install, I get an HRESULT E_FAIL error.  Example:  When I open VS2019, I am told that I need to update Data Lake Services and LIve Share VSIXs.  I click to update both and that the update will happen when I close all VS windows.  When I close VS2019, the install begins and I get this error immediately.  Also, if I try to install ANY new VSIX I get this same error.
     My VS2019 is fully updated, I am admin and I have connectivity OK.

```
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - 16.2.3073
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - Command line parameters:
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Community,/skuVersion:16.2.29209.62,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\borjeo\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXcixtpa1i.vsix,C:\Users\borjeo\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXpzsjnww4.vsix,C:\Users\borjeo\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIX2wlszo4g.vsix
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
8/18/2019 12:49:35 PM - -------------------------------------------
8/18/2019 12:49:36 PM - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupInstance2.GetState()
   at VSIXInstaller.SetupExtensions.GetLaunchableInstances(ISetupConfiguration2 configuration)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.EnumerateIsolatedInstalls(Action`1 callback)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.AddInstalledLocationBasedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.InitializeSupportedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.InitializeSupportedSKUs(ICommandLineData cmdLineData, IntPtr duplicatedUserToken)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Comment: Repair VS install

Comment: I did a repair install and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Visual Studio download cache folder( c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages) in your external hard disk or somewhere when installing Visual Studio because of not enough space of your computer, then you have to connect the external hard disk whenever you install external programs in your Visual Studio. 
 Usually it is recommended to set the VS download cache folder in your PC.
When you uninstall a VSIX program( i.e an added external programs), you also need the VS download cache folder. Without it, you can NOT uninstall a external program.
  Check where you saved the VS download cache folder when you installed VS.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/set-defaults-for-enterprise-deployments?view=vs-2019